# Adding the same layer in a subview changes its visual position

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer, swift-playground

I added a subview (with a black border) in a view and centered it.

Then I generate 2 identical triangles with CAShapeLayer and add one to the subview and the other to the main view.

Here is the visual result in Playground where we can see that the green triangle is totally off and should have been centered.

[image: Playground result]

And here is the code:

```
let view = UIView()
let borderedView = UIView()
var containedFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

func setupUI() {
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 600)
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    borderedView.frame = containedFrame
    borderedView.center = view.center
    borderedView.backgroundColor = .clear
    borderedView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    borderedView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    view.addSubview(borderedView)
    setupTriangles()
}

private func setupTriangles() {
    view.layer.addSublayer(createTriangle(color: .red)) // RED triangle
    borderedView.layer.addSublayer(createTriangle(color: .green)) // GREEN triangle
}

private func createTriangle(color: UIColor) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -containedFrame.width, y: 0))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -containedFrame.height))
    bezierPath.close()
    layer.position = borderedView.center
    layer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    layer.fillColor = color.cgColor
    return layer
}
```

**Note**: All `position` (of view, the borderedView and both triangles) are the same `(150.0, 300.0)`

**Question**: Why is the green layer not in the right position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@DuncanC is right that each view has its own coordinate system.  Your problem is this line:

```
layer.position = borderedView.center
```

That sets the layer's position to the center of the frame for the borderedView which is in the coordinate system of `view`.  When you create the green triangle, it needs to use the coordinate system of `borderedView`.

You can fix this by passing the view to your `createTriangle` function, and then use the center of the `bounds` of that view as the layer position:

```
private func setupTriangles() {
    view.layer.addSublayer(createTriangle(color: .red, for: view)) // RED triangle
    borderedView.layer.addSublayer(createTriangle(color: .green, for: borderedView)) // GREEN triangle
}

private func createTriangle(color: UIColor, for view: UIView) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -containedFrame.width, y: 0))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -containedFrame.height))
    bezierPath.close()
    layer.position = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    layer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    layer.fillColor = color.cgColor
    return layer
}
```

Note:  When you do this, the green triangle appears directly below the red one, so it isn't visible.

Comment: Well done finding the "smoking gun" that caused the specific behavior. (voted.) I didn't look at the OP's code that closely.

Comment: Thanks @DuncanC.  I find it fun working on visual problems when the OP provides their code.

Comment: So did you copy/paste the code into a project or playground and debug it, or did you review the code manually?

Comment: @DuncanC, I reviewed the code manually and identified the problem line.  I did not identify the problem by printing out values or stepping through the code.  I then put the code into a project and worked out the fix. It certainly helped that I've run into this type of problem before.

Answer (score 2):

Every view/layer uses the coordinate system of it's superview/superlayer. If you add a layer to self.view.layer, it will be positioned in self.view.layer's coordinate system. If you add a layer to borderedView.layer, it will be in borderedView.layer's coordinate system.

Think of the view/layer hierarchy as stacks of pieces of graph paper. You place a new piece of paper on the current piece (the superview/layer) in the current piece's coordinates system, but then if you draw on the new view/layer, or add new views/layer inside that one, you use the new view/layer's coordinate system.

Comment: I understand your answer but I still can't see why the green triangle is totally not inside the subview (the bordered view) where it has been added. The green triangle has its path starting at (0, 0), shouldn't it be placed at the center of the bordered view? (I couldn't edit my typo, so I rewrote it)